# moving local data to google cloud bucket using python api

Tags: google-cloud-storage, bucket

I can move data in google storage to buckets using the following:

```
gsutil cp afile.txt gs://my-bucket
```

How to do the same using the python api library:

```
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client()

# Make an authenticated API request
buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
print(buckets)
```

Cant find anything more than the above.

Comment: Hi Mpizos, do you mean upload data to a cloud storage bucket (e.g. from your local machine)?

Comment: @Paul yes. Not necessarily from local machine. But generally how to move data to a cloud storage bucket with the python api

Answer (score 4):

There is an API Client Library code sample code [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python).  My code typically looks like below which is a slight variant on the code they provide:

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client(project='<myprojectname>')
mybucket = storage.bucket.Bucket(client=client, name='mybucket')
mydatapath = 'C:\whatever\something' + '\\'   #etc
blob = mybucket.blob('afile.txt')
blob.upload_from_filename(mydatapath + 'afile.txt')
```

In case it is of interest, another method is to run the "gsutil" command line how you have typed in your Original Post using the subprocess command, e.g.:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("gsutil cp afile.txt gs://mybucket/", shell=True)
```

In my view, there are pros and cons of both methods depending on what you are trying to achieve - the latter method allows multi-threading if you have many files to upload whereas the former method perhaps allows better control, specification of metadata for each file, etc.

Comment: I would like to add to Paul's answer two links that may be of help. 

 [Cloud Storage Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) and
[GIT: Python GCS samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/storage)

Comment: `shell=True` may have security vulnerabilities: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess